# Converting between coordinate spaces SpriteKit

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, floating-point-conversion

I have a node with the shape of a box in a scene. The shape node should have its own coordinate space, so if I declare a point at (100,100) in the nodes coordinate space and rotate the box pi/4 rad the point should change in the scenes coordinate space.

My problem is I cant get this to work, I'm using the following code to convert a point in the nodes coord space to the scenes coord space, the placement of the node is 200,200 in the scene:

```
startPointInNodeSpace = CGPointMake(0, size.height/2);
CGPoint start = [self.scene convertPoint:CGPointMake(startPointInNodeSpace.x, startPointInNodeSpace.y) fromNode:self.parent];
CGPoint end = [self.scene convertPoint:CGPointMake(startPointInNodeSpace.x, startPointInNodeSpace.y + 100) fromNode:self.parent];
NSLog(@"start position in node: (%f,%f)\nend position in node: (%f,%f)",startPointInNodeSpace.x,startPointInNodeSpace.y,startPointInNodeSpace.x,startPointInNodeSpace.y + 100);
NSLog(@"start position in scene: (%f,%f)\nend position in scene: (%f,%f)",start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);
```

The code is inside a subclass of `SKSpriteNode`.

My log:

```
start position in node: (0.000000,20.000000)
end position in node: (0.000000,120.000000)
start position in scene: (0.000000,20.000000)
end position in scene: (0.000000,120.000000)
```

As you can see it is not converting the points at all but I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Visual Illustration of what I want to achieve:

[image: Conversion]

Comment: Is `self` here the blue box, or a child of the blue box?

Comment: self is the blue box which is a SKSpriteNode with position = 200,200. it is a child of the scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the following code in the scene to rotate the node:

```
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle: M_PI/4.0 duration:0];
[MYNODE runAction: rotation];
```

When I changed it to this inside the nodeclass instead it worked as expected:

```
self.zRotation = M_PI/4;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you're converting from `self.parent` instead of `self` — the node's parent *is* the scene, so there's no conversion to be done. Try converting from `self` instead:

```
startPointInNodeSpace = CGPointMake(0, size.height/2);
endPointInNodeSpace = CGPointMake(startPointInNodeSpace.x, startPointInNodeSpace.y + 100);
CGPoint start = [self.scene convertPoint:startPointInNodeSpace fromNode:self];
CGPoint end = [self.scene convertPoint:endPointInNodeSpace fromNode:self];
```

(Note that you can just pass `startPointInNodeSpace` into the method, rather than creating an identical point. Structs are copied by value, so the method can't mutate your variable.)

Comment: then i get:
    start position in node: (0.000000,20.000000)
    end position in node: (0.000000,120.000000)
    start position in scene: (200.000000,220.000000)
    end position in scene: (200.000000,320.000000)

which doesnt seem right either?

Comment: Sounds like the conversion method doesn't take rotation into account.

Comment: maybe the coord space isnt rotating when the node is?